# PHP form validation where value is not null

Tags: php, validation, isnumeric

When attempting to validate a field, it doesn't seem to work. I need to only perform `!is_numeric` when `$postcode` is not `null`. I do have client side validation, but I want to ensure that I have server side validation too.

code:

```
else if(!is_null($postcode) && !is_numeric($postcode))  
{
    $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="FF0000">Postcode must be a numeric value.</font></h4>';
}
```

Comment: what error you get it from the server?

Comment: The code you've posted is fine apart from there isn't a semicolon at the end of the 2nd line. Like @Ranjith said, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `$postcode`  comes from either a `$POST` or `$GET`, it always is a string. `!is_null()` will, therefore be FALSE, regardless:

```
php> var_dump(is_null(""))
#=> bool(false)
```

You could revert to using `empty()`, which is more liberal. However, PHP is utterly inconsistent and weird when it comes to these checks. For example, `empty()` will return `FALSE` for 0 too. Yup.

```
php> $postcode = "";
php> var_dump(empty($postcode))
#=> bool(true)
php> $postcode = 0;
php>var_dump(empty($postcode))
#=> bool(true)
```

A  much better approach, is to do some sort of "[duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)". In your case: when it can be converted to a numeric value, do that and use it. Then leave it to the language to determine what it considers "number-ish" enough to convert.

```
php> var_dump((int) "")
int(0)
php> var_dump((int) "13")
int(13)
```

So:

```
else if(($postcode = (int) $postcode) && ($postcode > 0)) {
}
```

And last, off-topic: a heed of warning about your business assumptions: postcodes are not always numeric. Yes, in the US most are. But there are more countries out there (saying this as a EU-citizen who comes way too often about sites that assume everyone is an average-US-citizen)

Answer (score 2):

maybe you want to use empty() function on strlen() function because is_null() checks NULL value. If $postcode is == "" it's not NULL.

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php
```

than you can use

```
else if(!empty($postcode) && !is_numeric($postcode))  {
```

or

```
else if(strlen($postcode) > 0 && !is_numeric($postcode))  {
```

or

```
else if($postcode != "" && !is_numeric($postcode))  {
```

As specified in the link, if you want to use is_null, is better to use $postcode !== NULL.
Much faster

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
else if(!empty($postcode) && !is_numeric($postcode))  {
  $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="FF0000">Postcode must be a numeric value.</font></h4>';
}
```

Hope this helps